# Why can't I sign up to Intel XDK?

Tags: json, intel-xdk

I can't seem to sign up to Intel XDK, I get the following error:

> sendCommand : Error Parsing JSON Response

**Intel XDK Version:** xdk_web_win_master_0769

Comment: intel-xdk version xdk_web_win_master_0769

Comment: Can you share the code you try to run?

Comment: I am not run code . I just setup intel xdk and i cant make account (sign up) on it . Without account i can't use the program

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information regarding what you are doing and what is occurring, but it might be worth noting that Intel XDK is no longer around therefore the services themselves might have been retired (or they might no longer allow new registrations).

> NOTE: As of August 16, 2017, Intel® App Preview has been retired and is no longer available in the respective mobile app stores; if you already have a copy of Intel App Preview on your test device it will continue to work, but you can no longer download it from a mobile store for new installations.

What I can suggest is what the XDK team were suggesting was to check out [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) or what I would suggest is use something like [Ionic](https://cordova.apache.org/)

For more information, please read [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/705276) article.